# Wrong sans serif font used by siunitx

Tags: fonts, siunitx

This is a problem that took me long to figure out, posting it here in the help it is useful.

The problem is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[font={sf}]{caption}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{detect-family=true}

\usepackage[scaled]{berasans}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  Dummy figure
  \caption{Caption with units: \SI{10}{m} vs 10~m}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Without the `\usepackage[scaled]{berasans}` line, everything works perfectly fine, and the fonts in the legend are homogeneous. However, with the redefinition of the default sans serif font, there is a significant mismatch between the fonts of the `\SI{10}{m}` command in the legend and the following `10~m` (and yes, I know the spacing is wrong but that's not the point).

Answer (score 3):

It took me forever to realize that the problem was that the output of the `\SI` command  is not typeset using `\sfdefault`, but using `\mathsf`, which is not redefined by the `\usepackage[scaled]{berasans}`.

My fix was to add the following in the preamble:

```
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{T1}{fvs}{m}{n}
```

This redefines the default family for `\mathsf` ot be the same as what the `berasans` package defines as the `\sfdefault` family.